# Semantic UI React Dropdown Search - Access autocomplete suggestion on close or enter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, semantic-ui-react

Versions:

- semantic-ui-react: ^0.88.2
- react: ^16.12.0

I have the following:

```
<Form.Select
    options={form.autocompleteOptions}
    search
    onSearchChange={handleAutocompleteSearch}
    label="CVE Code"
    placeholder="CVE Code"
/>
```

[image: Search input with autocomplete showcase]

The autocomplete suggestions work well, and when I press the return key, the rendered label changes to the current option in the menu. However, the value of the Dropdown is not updated and I can't find a way to access it. I am trying to access the value from inside the "onSearchChange" event handler.

In all of the examples below I can only get whatever the user has typed manually into the searchbox, not the "autocompleted" value, even though the renderLabel has changed.

I have tried:

1. Using the onChange event handler, this never triggers
2. Using the Dropdown component directly instead of a Form.Select, but I still cannot access the updated value
3. Using the onKeyDownHandler to catch whenever the uses presses "Enter". This event does not seem to provide me with the full value either.
4. Using a ref to access the DOM element. I was not able to access the ref, perhaps I was using it wrong.
5. Creating a controlled component using the value, however I am not able to update the state to the autocompleted value as I can not access it from any event handler. Image of the dropdown is provided below:

It seems like I might need to use the Semantic UI Search component instead since this has a onResultSelect event handler, but I feel like it should also be possible to use a Dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Semantic-UI-React will emit the events as data which is in object consists of the values
i would say try using onChange event handler as

```
const handleChange = (e, data) => {
console.log(data.value);
};
```

or in case search query option use as below,

```
const handleSearch = (e, data) => {
console.log(data.searchQuery);
};
```

let me know if that helps, refer official docs [here](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/)

Comment: Sadly I have read the official docs extensively. There is no onChange handler available for the Form.Select option.

Comment: @MortenHauge : you may check out live demo in [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60525749/11299053) that proves ***there certainly is onChange handler*** and it works as expected